# How to access array item within a class in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom, canvas

I am using an open source js library [Cesium](http://cesiumjs.org).  In this js a class is defined as a container with empty array [].  A push is used to add to this array.  The HTML display this whole container as a canvas.  I want to add a tool tip using jquery for each item of the array, but don't know how to do it.  I am able to add a tool tip for the container, but not the items within its container.
In the below code, class "cesium-timeline-tracks" is the one I am interested in.

Please help. Below is the snipet of the code:

Javascript file:

```
    function Timeline(container, clock) {
    container = getElement(container);

    this.container = container;

    var topDiv = document.createElement('div');
    topDiv.className = 'cesium-timeline-main';
    container.appendChild(topDiv);
    this._topDiv = topDiv;

    this._topDiv.innerHTML = '<div class="cesium-timeline-trackContainer">' +
    '<canvas class="cesium-timeline-tracks" width="10" height="1">' +
    '</canvas></div><div class="cesium-timeline-bar"></div><div class="cesium-timeline-needle"></div><span class="cesium-timeline-ruler"></span>';

    this._trackContainer = this._topDiv.childNodes[0];
    this._trackListEle = this._topDiv.childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
    this._timeBarEle = this._topDiv.childNodes[1];
    this._needleEle = this._topDiv.childNodes[2];
    this._rulerEle = this._topDiv.childNodes[3];
    this._context = this._trackListEle.getContext('2d');

    this._trackList = [];
    this._highlightRanges = [];
```

Each item in the array is added using push:

```
Timeline.prototype.addTrack = function(interval, heightInPx, color, backgroundColor) {
    /* EN added parameter id*/
    var newTrack = new TimelineTrack(interval, heightInPx, color, backgroundColor);
    this._trackList.push(newTrack);
    this._lastHeight = undefined;
    this.resize();
    return newTrack;
};
```

To add an item, I just need to call timeline.addTrack(...);
Below is how I use it for the cesium-timeline-tracks class, but I want to use for the item I have in the array _trackList.  Please help.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cesium-timeline-tracks").attr("title", "This is a tooltip for the timetracks.");
    $(document).tooltip({
        position: {
        my: "left bottom-20",
        at: "left top"
        }
    });
});
```

Implement Ted's suggestion, but still does not show for each item, only the whole container.  Below is the code.  Note that timeline variable was created previously which is a timeline container(not shown in code).  I tried viewer.timeline._trackList, but that caused the tool tip to disappear all together.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     //$(".cesium-timeline-tracks").attr("title", "This is a tooltip for the timetracks.");
    $.each(viewer.timeline, function (index, element) {
        $(element).attr("title", "tooltip for " + index);
        $(element).tooltip ({
            position: {
            my: "left bottom-20",
            at: "left top"
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Changed viewer.timeline to viewer.timeline._trackList in .each, got errortype "d.addEventListener is not a function" in jquery-1.11.0.min.js.  The console shows index 0 as [object Object].

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(viewer.timeline._trackList, function (index, element) {
      console.log("****** the index " + index + " is " + element + ".");
$(element).attr("title", "tooltip for " + index);
    $(element).tooltip ({
        position: {
                  my: "left bottom-20",
            at: "left top"
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Output on console: the index 0 is [object Object].

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing Cesium, my first impression would be to iterate the array with `$.each`...

```
$.each(Timeline._trackList, function(index, element){

      $(element).tooltip ...

});
```

[jQuery .each Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  It looks like that's the one I need to use.  However, when I tried that out and there's an error about syntax error: missing ; before statement $(element).tooltip

Comment: I am tryin to put the code in but whenever I enter it exits me out.  let me edit the original post then

Comment: Oh, I see why.  I am missing a '(' after .tooltip.  Modified code to reflect what I have now.

Comment: Is there anything else I can try?  Is it because this object (viewer.timeline) is displayed as a canvas?  thanks

Comment: Without a live example, it's really hard to say

Comment: I can't add any image because I don't have 10 reputation yet.  Otherwise, you'll be able to see what I am trying to do. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Inside the .each, I log to console the element.  Only the first one's info is written out: the index 0 is [object Object].  There's type error from jquery-1.11.0.min.js: a.addEventListener is not a function.  I think jquery does not recognize this array.  Any idea? Thanks